# month array from to two input form

Tags: php, html

EDIT:

How Do I **output**

the months from two forms

```
$_POST['FromMonth'] = "January";
$_POST['ToMonth'] = "May";
```

Output result:

```
"January, February, March, April, May"
```

I know this is for loop basic php
But I'm kinda confused right now.

Comment: why are you using text fields? this seems counter intuitive.. Use a dropdown and use the selected index to print out the months as the from and to values

Comment: I'm using the select but my codes is long thats why I just use input type text as exmple.

Comment: Start with proper `foreach` syntax: http://php.net/manual/pl/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Another thing, in your HTML your variable for "from month" is FM, in your code it magically becomes TF.

Comment: right lol sorry bout that .

Comment: assign a numerical value to each month in your dropdown, grab that number, then do a for loop while i>=firstnumber to i <=lastnumber echo months at position i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I create a function that returns the list of month numbers. This permits wrapping, so the output could be: 10, 11, 0, 1, 2 for November, December, January, February, March.

```
function get_months_in_period($from, $to)
{
    $months = array();

    if ($to >= $from) {
      $months = range($from, $to); 
    } else {   
      $months = array_merge(range($from, 11), range(0, $to));
    } 

    return $months;
}
```

Secondly, I use the following code for display.

```
// Get $from and $to from your HTML form.
$from = 8;
$to = 2;

// Hard coded for reference.
$month_names = array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");

// Initialize our variable.
$months_in_period = '';

// Display all the months in the period.
foreach (get_months_in_period($from, $to) as $index) {

    // Just echo.
    echo $month_names[$index] . ' ';

   // Save as a variable.
   $months_in_period .= $month_names[$index] . ' ';
}

// Trim the ending whitespace.
$months_in_period = rtrim($months_in_period);

var_dump($months_in_period);
```

Comment: this is what I'm looking for thank you so much.
hello another question How can I make a variable from it? from the output?

Comment: $b='';
foreach (get_months_in_period($from, $to) as $index) {
 $a= $month_names[$index] . ' ';  

$b .= $a.'';
 }
 
echo $b
tis solve my problem. thanks

Comment: No problem. I updated my code to show how to save as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

`foreach` doesn't work the way you seem to think it does. What you haven't isn't even valid PHP syntax.

Here's a solution to your problem. Given you already have the strings in $FM and $TM and the $months array already created:

```
$FMI=array_search($FM,$months);
$TMI=array_search($TM,$months);

$slice=array_slice($months,$FMI,$TMI-$FMI+1); // +1 because you want it to be inclusive

echo implode(", ",$slice);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want, but only if the names are entered to the input fields exactly like you have them in your array.

```
$output = false;

foreach($months as $month) {
    if ($month == $TF) $output = true;
    if ($output) echo $month;
    if ($month == $TM) break;
}
```